# How do you apply 'or' to all values of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, reduce

How do you apply 'or' to all values of a list in Python? I'm thinking something like:

```
or([True, True, False])
```

or if it was possible:

```
reduce(or, [True, True, False])
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The built-in function `any` does what you want:

```
>>> any([True, True, False])
True
>>> any([False, False, False])
False
>>> any([False, False, True])
True
```

`any` has the advantage over `reduce` of shortcutting the test for later items in the sequence once it finds a true value. This can be very handy if the sequence is a generator with an expensive operation behind it. For example:

```
>>> def iam(result):
...  # Pretend this is expensive.
...  print "iam(%r)" % result
...  return result
... 
>>> any((iam(x) for x in [False, True, False]))
iam(False)
iam(True)
True
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x or y, (iam(x) for x in [False, True, False]))
iam(False)
iam(True)
iam(False)
True
```

If your Python's version doesn't have `any()`, `all()` builtins then they are easily implemented as [Guido van Rossum suggested](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196):

```
def any(S):
    for x in S:
        if x:
            return True
    return False

def all(S):
    for x in S:
        if not x:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 7):

No one has mentioned it, but "`or`" is available as a function in the operator module:

```
from operator import or_
```

Then you can use `reduce` as above.

Would always advise "`any`" though in more recent Pythons.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> all([True,False,True])
False
>>> any([True,False,True])
True
```

Python 2.5 and up ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html))

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
reduce(lambda a,b: a or b, [True, True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

reduce should do it for you, shouldn't it?

```
>>> def _or(x, y):
...     return x or y
... 
>>> reduce(_or, [True, True, False])
True
```